# How to replace like/dislike word in comments in django project

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How to make the "like/dislike" words in django project change after user click.
In general, this system of likes/dislikes by ip works. But the words "like-dislike" do not change after clicking on their button.

**models.py:**

```
class Women(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    anons = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Анонс', null=True)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Ключові слова', null=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Текст статті')
    article_author = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='Автор', blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name='Фото', blank=True)
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Час створення')
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Час змінення')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Публікація')
    cat = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Категорії')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', kwargs={'post_pk': self.pk})

class IpModel(models.Model):
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ip

class Comments(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Women, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Статья', blank=True, null=True, related_name='comments_women')
    comm_author = models.TextField(max_length=30, verbose_name='', null=True)
    create_data = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Дата создания', auto_now=True)
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(IpModel, related_name='posts_likes', blank=True)

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

**views.py:**

```
class ShowPost(DataMixin, DetailView, FormMixin):
    model = Women
    template_name = 'women/post.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'post_pk'
    context_object_name = 'post'
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        c_def = self.get_user_context(title=context['post'])
        return dict(list(context.items()) + list(c_def.items()))

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.path

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.article = self.get_object()
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

def get_client_ip(requset):
    x_forwared_for = requset.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwared_for:
        ip = x_forwared_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = requset.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip

def postLike(request, pk):
    post_id = request.POST.get('blog-id')
    return_path = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/')
    post = Comments.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    ip = get_client_ip(request)
    if not IpModel.objects.filter(ip=ip).exists():
        IpModel.objects.create(ip=ip)
    if post.likes.filter(id=IpModel.objects.get(ip=ip).id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(IpModel.objects.get(ip=ip))
    else:
        post.likes.add(IpModel.objects.get(ip=ip))
    return redirect(return_path)
```

In general, this system of likes/dislikes by ip works. But the words "like-dislike" do not change after clicking on their button.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfD4d.png)

I want to change the word "like\dislike" when I click on the "like\dislike" button. Something in that style.

**post.html**

```
{% for item in post.comments_women.all %}
<li>
    <p class="total-likes">{{item.total_likes}} likes</p>
    <p class="author-name">{{item.comm_author}}</p>
    <p class="date-com">{{item.create_data}}</p>
    <p class="date-text">{{item.text}}</p>

    <form action="{% url 'blog_like' pk=item.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" name="blog-id" value="{{ item.id }}" class="like-btn">
            {% if like_status %}
                Unlike
            {% else %}
                Like
            {% endif %}
        </button>
    </form>
    
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You forgot to pass `like_status` from the view to the template. And I'd suggest to use a little more abstract name for your _main_ model.

Comment: I can't pass "like_status" to the class ShowPost(from views.py) because it refers to "model = Women" and doesn't see the "likes" field (from models.py). I need somehow to reference the "Comments" model(from models.py). Perhaps you can suggest a way?